# C0mbinatorics: Minimum number of node transitions

Tags: combinatorics

For n nodes, labeled 1,2...,n, a total of x nodes can be on at a time. Each node must "visit" each of the other nodes, and a node can only visit another node when both are on. Each time nodes are turned on/off is considered a transition. What is the minimum number of transitions?
EDIT: Turning a node off happens in the same time as turning a node on, so in each transition you can turn nodes on and off at the same time. This means that each transition is simply the grouping of nodes that are on,

I have not studied combinatorics in a few years: is there a formula for answering this? And a way to output which nodes (1,2,...) are on at each transition? Right now I am using a brute-force program to find all combinations of transitions that accomplishes the goal of each node visiting all the other nodes, and picking the best case, but this has to be hardcoded for each x, so I am hoping that there is a better way.

Comment: Assuming they all begin in the off position, here's a basic lower bound:

Turn on the first $x$ nodes ($x$ transitions). Now $\binom{x}{2}$ pairs of nodes can visit one another.
Assume it then takes $k$ off/on moves ($2k$ transitions) to accomplish the goal. For each off/on move, at most $x-1$ new pairs can visit one another. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of nodes in total, so $\binom{x}{2} + k(x-1) \geq \binom{n}{2}$, and thus $k \geq \frac{n(n-1)}{2(x-1)} - \frac{x}{2}$.
Thus, the number of total transitions is $x + 2k \geq \frac{n(n-1)}{(x-1)}$.

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually achieve that lower bound, however. I played around with it a bit and couldn't see a way to make the algorithm work. Do you have any exact values for small $n$ and $x$?

Comment: @PerryIverson Here are some values ... for (x=4, n=10)=9; (x=4, n=7)=5; (x=4, n=6)=3; (x=4, n=5)=3; (x=4, n=4)=1. (x=3, n=10)=18; (x=3, n=7)=7; (x=3,n=5)=4; (x=3,n=4)=3.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding your question then. A few points to clarify: 1. What is a transition? Turning off one node and on another, turning off or on a single node, or turning x nodes off and x nodes on? 2. Do all nodes begin off?

Comment: @PerryIverson Sorry for being unclear - 1. a transition is turning x nodes on + off. So at each transition we can turn all x nodes off and at the same time turn on the next next x nodes - this still counts as 1 transition. A better way of explaining it could be: what is the minimum number of groupings of at most x nodes such that every node is grouped with n-1 nodes at some point? So for (x=3, n=4) the value is 3, because you turn on nodes (1,2,3), then (1,2,4), then (3,4). 2. No, ie the transition of all nodes being off is not counted; you start counting when at least 1 node is on.